# while loop condition not fullfiled

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, do-while

```c
double randomx,randomy,randomz,dia;
#define DROP_RAD 60
#define particleradi 3

for (i = 0; i<30; i++) 
{
    {
        randomx=2*((float)rand()/RAND_MAX)-1;
        randomy=2*((float)rand()/RAND_MAX)-1;
        randomz=2*((float)rand()/RAND_MAX)-1;
        randomx=randomx*(DROP_RAD -2*particleradi);
        randomy=randomy*(DROP_RAD -2*particleradi);
        randomz=randomz*(DROP_RAD -2*particleradi);
        
        dia=randomx*randomx+randomy*randomy+randomz*randomz;
        dia=sqrt(dia);
    
    } while(dia>DROP_RAD);

    
    printf(" id=%d, x=%lf, y=%lf, z=%lf , dia=%lf\n ",i,randomx,randomy,randomz,dia);
```

I'm getting values for dia greater than DROP_RAD even though the while condition is supposed to this. Kindly help.

Comment: Your `while` loop, as it stands, is an empty one. Have you, perhaps, forgotten a `do` at the beginning?

Comment: Notice when indented properly, your `for` loop is never closed and your `do` loop is missing the `do` -- that won't even compile. Do you have the rest to post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a [do-while-loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_while_loop) here. It will execute the block of code at least once, and then either repeatedly execute the block, or stop executing it, depending on the boolean condition at the end of the block.

```
do {
    /* here goes your code */
} while (dia > DROP_RAD);
```

If you don't want the block to be executed at all when the condition is `false`, you have to move the condition to the beginning of the block.

```
while (dia > DROP_RAD) {
    /* here goes your code */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet is equivalent to the following

```
for (i = 0; i<30; i++) 
{

    {
        randomx=2*((float)rand()/RAND_MAX)-1;
        randomy=2*((float)rand()/RAND_MAX)-1;
        randomz=2*((float)rand()/RAND_MAX)-1;
        randomx=randomx*(DROP_RAD -2*particleradi);
        randomy=randomy*(DROP_RAD -2*particleradi);
        randomz=randomz*(DROP_RAD -2*particleradi);
  
        dia=randomx*randomx+randomy*randomy+randomz*randomz;
        dia=sqrt(dia);
    }

    while(dia>DROP_RAD);


    printf(" id=%d, x=%lf, y=%lf, z=%lf , dia=%lf\n ",i,randomx,randomy,randomz,dia);

    //...
```

That is you have a compound statement

```
    {
        randomx=2*((float)rand()/RAND_MAX)-1;
        // ...
    }
```

followed by a separate while statement

```
while(dia>DROP_RAD);
```

So either you have an infinite `while` loop

```
while(dia>DROP_RAD);
```

if `dia` is greater than `DROP_RAD` or the loop is interrupted at once if the condition is not satisfied.

It seems you mean a do-while loop like

```
do {
    randomx=2*((float)rand()/RAND_MAX)-1;
    randomy=2*((float)rand()/RAND_MAX)-1;
    randomz=2*((float)rand()/RAND_MAX)-1;
    randomx=randomx*(DROP_RAD -2*particleradi);
    randomy=randomy*(DROP_RAD -2*particleradi);
    randomz=randomz*(DROP_RAD -2*particleradi);

    dia=randomx*randomx+randomy*randomy+randomz*randomz;
    dia=sqrt(dia);
} while(dia>DROP_RAD);
```